# using `react-select` with `nextjs` causes Hydration Error when `Select` element is filled with value from localStorage

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-select, hydration

Using NextJS, I have a form which uses `react-select`'s `CreatableSelect` component with multiselect. This form stores the data from `react-hook-forms`'s state in the localStorage using the following hook:

```js
// useLocalStorage
import { useMemo, useState } from 'react';

export default function useLocalStorage<T>(key: string, initialValue: T) {
    // State to store our value
    // Pass initial state function to useState so logic is only executed once
    const [storedValue, setStoredValue] = useState<T>(() => {
        if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
            return initialValue;
        }

        try {
            // Get from local storage by key
            const item = window.localStorage.getItem(key);
            // Parse stored json or if none return initialValue
            return item ? JSON.parse(item) : initialValue;
        } catch (error) {
            // If error also return initialValue
            console.log(error);
            return initialValue;
        }
    });

    // Return a wrapped version of useState's setter function that ...
    // ... persists the new value to localStorage.
    const setValue = useMemo(
        () => (value: T | ((val: T) => T)) => {
            try {
                // Allow value to be a function so we have same API as useState
                const valueToStore =
                    value instanceof Function ? value(storedValue) : value;
                // Save state
                setStoredValue(valueToStore);
                // Save to local storage
                if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
                    window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(valueToStore));
                }
            } catch (error) {
                // A more advanced implementation would handle the error case
                console.log(error);
            }
        },
        [key, storedValue],
    );

    return [storedValue, setValue] as const;
}
```

But when the storage contains the values for the `CreatableSelect` component, which is filled after fetching from the localStorage, it throws this error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error

Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

# and

Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <div> in <div>.
```

This only happens when the `CreatableSelect` component is filled with value from the localStorage. When the storage is empty, the error isn't thrown.

The page doesn't use SSR or SSG, i.e., the page file only exports the component itself, and no `getServerProps` or similar functions.

This is a tuned down version of the page:

```js
const Page: NextPage = () => {
    const [formDraft, setFormDraft] = useLocalStorage<
        UseFormProps<FormValues>['defaultValues']
    >(projectSubmitFormDraftStorageKey, {});

    const { register, handleSubmit, control, watch } = useForm<FormValues>({
        shouldUseNativeValidation: true,
        defaultValues: formDraft,
    });

    // save form data to localStorage
    useEffect(() => {
        const { unsubscribe } = watch(formData => setFormDraft(formData));
        return () => unsubscribe();
    }, [setFormDraft, watch]);

    return (
        <Controller
            name='tags'
            control={control}
            render={({ field: { value, onChange, onBlur } }) => (
                <CreatableSelect
                    placeholder='Choose...'
                    instanceId='tags'
                    inputId='tags'
                    options={filteredTagsToSelectOptions(tags ?? [])}
                    isLoading={isTagsLoading}
                    allowCreateWhileLoading
                    createOptionPosition='last'
                    isMulti
                    onChange={options => onChange(options?.map(option => option.value))}
                    value={valuesToSelectOptions(value)}
                    onBlur={onBlur}
                />
            )}
        />
    );
}
```

How do I fix this? Do I add some default value to the `CreatableSelect` component, which I should remove once rendered?

Comment: >The page doesn't use SSR or SSG.

Are you sure? This is tagged with Next.js. Show us how you render this only on the client

Comment: I guess I should have better worded it. The page file itself doesn't export a `getStaticProps` or `getServerProps` or anything similar. The file only exports the component itself. I'll make the edit

Comment: Alright, but that might be the reason for the rehydration mismatch. On the server you're always using the initialValue, but then on the client side the localstorage might contain some data. This does then not match what you rendered on the server.  This blog post might explain the issue. I recommend looking into the proposed <ClientOnly> solution when using localstorage (which of course is not available on the server): https://www.joshwcomeau.com/react/the-perils-of-rehydration/

Comment: @Olavi thanks for linking the blog. I kinda knew the concept behind it, but the blog has cleared it up a lot. It also solved the issue.

Comment: Nice to hear that! Should've posted it as an answer maybe...

Comment: Did you solve this, if so, how?